# Conversion of coloured image to grey scale image (512 shades of grey) in java

Tags: java, image-processing

I am trying to convert a colored image to grayscale. The result should be 512 shades of grey.

How can I convert the pixel value to 9 bit so that I get 512 shades?

Comment: If you have code, you should include it so that people can help identify the problem.

Comment: I dont have a code yet. I would include it as soon as i start with it. I am just asking if you have an idea about getting 512 shades for a grayscale image.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to do it in 9 bits but if you want value of your image in range of 0 to 511, this can be done in following manner.

```
im = imread('lena.png'); 
im = double(im);
gray = 0.2989*im(:,:,1)+0.5870*im(:,:,2)+0.1140*im(:,:,3);
gray  = 511*mat2gray(gray); % scale image b/w 0 and 1;
```

This is my thought, please give us some more explanation with your code, so that anyone here can suggest solution of your problem.

Thank You

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would definitely add it once i do it. i would try with your code.